# Out of memory Exception on Listview with images and text

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, bitmap

My App has run out of memory due to a ListView with an `ImageView` and 2 `TextView`'s inside. The images are big and I shrink them down to `56x56dp` in `single_row.xml` for the ListView, but they are also used in larger sizes on other screens.

The `MainActivity` calls the single_row into the listview and inflates it. Then the single row is duplicated with individual content for each row. Each row has an image and 2 textviews. I know there's a way to use bitmap but I'm unsure how to implement it in the code.

Here is the **main activity.java code**

```
@Override public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row=convertView;   
    if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup,false); 
    }
    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView description = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    SingleRow temp=list.get(i);
    title.setText(temp.title);
    description.setText(temp.description);
    image.setImageResource(temp.image);

    return row;
}
```

here is the **singlerow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="Large Text"    
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>`
```

Any solution would be helpful. I'm unsure how to implement it in this specific structure.

Comment: Just because you have set the size of the View to be 56dp does not mean you aren't loading the entire bitmap into memory first. Maybe this link will help you: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or real device? I had the same problem loading images in imageview, but the app seemed to work on real devices, correctly. If it didn't work try to set scaleType="fitCenter" on your imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Karakuri said, restricting the ImageView size to 56dpx56dp doesn't mean that the entire bitmap is not loaded. First load the bitmap from the file (or resource), and shrink it. Use

```
//For resource
image.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource("android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/image_name"));
 //For file
image.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(filepath));


public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 2;
    if (height >= reqHeight || width >= reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String file,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. One more question, would I add this to main activity.java or create a new java class and call it in main activity? Would this work with an entire set of 15 int[] images=  ?

Comment: @user3606168 You can declare it in a class and call it wherever you want :)